# The Mahayana faith and wisdom

Tags: mahayana, books, stages-of-the-path

I have a few questions about "wisdom", which I would personally define as it appears in Zhiyi's book the Great Calming and Contemplation, in the section on the six identities

> If one is endowed with both wisdom and faith, then upon hearing that a
>   single thought-moment is identical with the positive [aspect that are
>   conducive to bodhicitta], faith will keep one from denigrating [what
>   one does not understand], and wisdom will keep one from being
>   apprehensive [about one’s inability to attain enlightenment]. [In this
>   case,] both the beginning and later [stages] are positive. If one does
>   not have faith, then [one despairs i] the exalted levels of the
>   sage are not part of one’s own wisdom, 344 and if one does not have
>   wisdom, one becomes arrogant and thinks that one is already equal to a
>   Buddha.

IIs it possible to be on the path without wisdom? Is it possible to advance along it, even to attain complete, and perfect enlightenment, without wisdom?

And if the latter is in **any** way the case, then how so, and why would the practitioner have to fall "back" into complete ignorance in order have any semblance of enlightenment?

Forgive me if I speak crazily :) !!

Comment: To me this comes up like a question "can you ever learn walking without having balance/poise? - So can a child learn to walk without having already the ability to balance physically?" Well - most of us have learned to walk, and even missed the ability to have physical balance before...

Comment: Is it possible? Yes but IMO it's only for those that suffer from a mental or physical defect barring them from a deep understanding of the Dharma and enlightenment. One should always seek knowledge, wisdom and faith.

Answer (score 1):

> "IIs it possible to be on the path without wisdom? Is it possible to advance  >along it, even to attain complete, and perfect enlightenment, without wisdom?"

---

From mindfulness, clear comprehension arise, from clear comprehension, insight arise, from insight, wisdom arise.

Without wisdom one would not know skilful from unskilful action, appropriate from inappropriate body, speech and mind cultivation. How then can one purify oneself?

> "And if the latter is in any way the case, then how so, and why would the  >practitioner have to fall "back" into complete ignorance in order have any  >semblance of enlightenment?"

It is not the case that one can obtained enlightenment without wisdom. The word enlightenment itself also means wisdom. To be enlighten means to be wise.

Answer (score 0):

Wisdom is formed from the combination of knowledge and experience. Meditation can boost the cognitive processes forming wisdom, but even without meditation you can form wisdom.

As you move along the path, you will form wisdom.